# how to query to display column names except an array list

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

hey guys im looking for to show columns of a table  except some.  forexample my table name `mobile_table` has columns like :

- sony
- nokia
- apple
- LG
- Sumsung

...and i  need to show these columns except Sumsung ,LG

```
$exceptions_arr = "LG,Sumsung"
```

i know how to show column names of a table but not to apply exeption array filter !

```
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM mobile_table"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 

while($columns = mysql_fetch_array($result, MSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
  echo $columns;     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$exceptions_arr = array("LG",
                        "Sumsung"
                       );

while($columns = mysql_fetch_array($result, MSQL_ASSOC)) {  
   foreach($columns as $columnName => $columnValue)
   if (!in_array($columnName,$exceptions_arr)) {
      echo $columnValue; 
   }
}
```

Alternatively, select only the columns that you want rather than every column and then remove those you don't want

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't look like normalized table.
I recommend reading about normalization:
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html
http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/20-Nermalisation.html
http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/